# Java MySQL оперетор COUNT();

Tags: java, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть вот такой код:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(id_user) FROM forum.users");
while (resultSet.next()) {
    //int id_user = resultSet.getInt(1);
    //int id_user = resultSet.getInt("id_user");        
    System.out.println(id_user);
}
```

Почему вызывая метод с аргументом типа `int` (номер колонки) все работает (таки считает кол-во строк), а вызывая метод с аргументом типа `String` ("имя колонки") падаю по исключению

> java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id_user' not found.

Почему не находит?

При таком запросе ведь видит колонку!

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id_user FROM forum.users");
while(resultSet.next()) {
    String id_user = resultSet.getString("id_user");
    System.out.println(id_user);
}
```

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Хг :) сам разобрался.  не правильно указывал колонку! не знал что так нужно делать :)
 int id_topic = resultSet.getInt("COUNT(id_topic)");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `COUNT(id_user)` не называется `id_user`. Это вычисляемое поле, и оно не называется именем ни одного из полей таблицы. У него какое-нибудь название по умолчанию типа `Expr1`.

Вы можете, однако, дать свое собственное название (*field alias*) этому полю в возвращаемом наборе данных:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
  "SELECT COUNT(id_user) as UserCount FROM forum.users");
while (resultSet.next()) {
  int id_user = resultSet.getInt("UserCount");
  System.out.println(id_user);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо буду теперь знать!!!